# How move the two rows to top of data frame in a list in R?

Tags: r, list, row

There is a list of data frames that each data frame has different rows and columns. The bottom of each data frame is the total and percentage rows. I want to move the percentage row to the top (first) and the total second row in each data frame of the list.  this is a data frame sample:

```
structure(list(PROVINCE = c("31", "34", "35", "35", "36", "94", 
"94", "94", "94", "94", "Total", "Percentage"), DISTRICT = c("71", 
"4", "7", "73", "71", "71", "71", "71", "71", "71", "Total", 
"Percentage"), SUB_DISTRI = c("90", "70", "290", "50", "20", 
"21", "30", "40", "40", "40", "Total", "Percentage"), VILLAGE = c("5", 
"3", "1", "2", "12", "3", "6", "1", "2", "4", "Total", "Percentage"
), X0_NA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.5799999237061, 0, 1648.85999393463, 
0.110249308880496), X767_Sa.u..Sahu..Sahu.u..Sau = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.75, 0.000651923611185302), X805_Adihup..Atam..Borai..Hatam..Hattam..Mansim..Miriei..Tinam..Uran = c(0, 
20.239999771118, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 675.089997291566, 0.0451391906573737
), X814_Ajamaru..Atinjo..Mai.Brat..Maite..Majbrat..Maybrat..Mey.Brat = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3834.40999031067, 0.25638383668188
), X829_Arfak..Mansibaber..Meah..Mejach..Mejah..Meyach..Meyah = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 700.749998092649, 0.0468549199276567
), X859_Ayamaru..Brat..Maibrat = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 229.680000305176, 0.0153573143811273), X942_Fayu = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 214.599998474121, 0.0143490057400625), 
    X978_Kajupulau..Kayupulau = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 36.1599998474122, 0.00241780078779332)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible data. In the future, however, it would be better to post a more simplified version--what we call a *minimal* reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

```
# Calculating the row numbers
df[c(nrow(df), nrow(df)-1, 1:(nrow(df)-2)), ]

# Using `head` and `tail`
rbind(tail(df, 2)[2:1, ], head(df, -2))
```

Generalized as a function, you can do:

```
fun <- function(df) df[c(nrow(df), nrow(df)-1, 1:(nrow(df)-2)), ]
```

Then, you should be able to do:

```
lapply(lst_of_df, fun)
```

#### Demo

Here's a `list` of `data.frame`s with varying numbers of rows.

```
set.seed(1)
nrows <- sample(7, 5, TRUE)
lst <- lapply(nrows, function(x) {
  data.frame(row = c(paste0("row", seq_len(x)), "tot", "pct"),
             v1 = seq_len(x+2))
})
```

To change the order of rows for all of them, use:

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst, fun)
```

Comment: How to do in a list of data frames? Not just in a data frame.

Comment: @user14828029, please see the updates to see how you could convert it to a function that gets applied to all `data.frame`s in a `list`.

Comment: Thanks have done! Is it possible to sort the columns horizontally largest-to-smallest by total? total is the second row in each data frame.

Comment: @user14828029, you'd want to look at the `order` function. With `data.frame`s in R, you can rearrange them using the `data[row_order, column_order]` approach. Notice that `fun` was defined without specifying the column order.  You'd want to `unlist` the columns  with numeric values, determine their `order`, and combine that with the function to set the column order. I'd recommend playing around with that for a bit, and if you can't solve it, post another question.